# Can I Run docker on linux mint 13?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, linux-mint

I've tried to install docker on my machine, following the instructions for Precise 12.04 found [here](http://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/).

When I try:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

I get the result:

> Either your platform is not easily detectable, is not supported by this
>     installer script (yet - PRs welcome! [hack/install.sh]), or does not yet have
>     a package for Docker.  Please visit the following URL for more detailed
>     installation instructions:

```
https://docs.docker.com/en/latest/installation/
```

My kernel:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-61-generic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the short installer script to take a look at why it is giving you this message:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ >install-docker.sh
$EDITOR install-docker.sh
```

Doing that, I see several checks for `lsb_release`. Is your system missing that command? If so, [see this](https://askubuntu.com/a/393329/429687) to install it. Or maybe it’s not returning “ubuntu”. If you fix this, the docker installer script may work fine.

If that doesn’t work, you can hard-code a case for your OS (Mint?) in the `ubuntu|debian` case (line 243), like:

```
ubuntu|debian|linuxmint)  # or maybe you’ll need here: *)
```

When done editing (or installing `lsb_release`), run the script to see if it will complete:

```
sudo ./install-docker.sh
```

Comment: The part to add is actually `linuxmint` (lowercapsed from `lsb_release -si`) but doing that brings my Mint15 to not being able `[...] to locate package docker-engine`